# How to rewrite external URL's on static HTML pages using .htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site with hundreds of static HTML pages that have the same link to an external site at the bottom.

I need to change that external link in each page to point to a different external URL.

How can I use .htaccess to rewrite that link on those hundreds of static HTML pages and change it to something else without having to manually change it in those hundreds of individual files?

Comment: .htaccess cannot change your HTML source and cannot rewrite it either since hose URLs are all pointing to external site.

Comment: @anubhava: So is my only option to manually change the link on those hundreds of pages?